# numpyのmatrix型のデータを画像として出力したい

Tags: python, python3, numpy

`numpy.matrix`型の行列データがあります．これを行列の画像として出力したいのですが調べてもなかなか出てきません．`numpy.array`型なら色々方法はあるみたいですが，`numpy.matrix`型のデータに対して画像として出力，保存する方法はありますか？

以下がサンプルデータの一部です

```
A = np.matrix([
[0, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 0]
])
```

Comment: 例えばこのページに出てくる行列の図のようなものでしょうか？ [【行列式編】逆行列の求め方を画像付きで解説！](https://oguemon.com/study/linear-algebra/inverse-matrix/), [余因子と余因子展開](https://oguemon.com/study/linear-algebra/cofactor-expansion/)

Comment: @kunif そのような行列を表示したいです．説明が足りなくて申し訳ありません．

Comment: どんな手順で変換していけば良いのか知識がありませんが、こんなツール用のデータが作れれば出力出来そうです。[Where is the \matrix command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26434)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas`に`to_latex()`というメソッドがあって、`PyLaTeX`と(さらにLaTexのコンパイラと)組み合わせると、目的のものが出来そうです。こちらの記事に出ていました。
[how to print a data frame from pandas using pylatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/340349)
上記記事で承認後にもっと簡単に出来るよ、と付いた回答の方ですね。

> It might be noted, that pandas DataFrames already have a quite powerful`to_latex`method. Another approach that makes use of this method and does not reinvent the wheel would be:
>
> pandas DataFramesにはすでに非常に強力なto_latexメソッドがあることに注意してください。 この方法を利用し、車輪を再発明しない別のアプローチは次のとおりです。
>
> ```
> import numpy as np
> import pylatex as pl
> import pandas as pd
>
> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [9,8,7]})
> df.index.name = 'x'
>
> M = np.matrix(df.values)
>
> doc = pl.Document()
>
> doc.packages.append(pl.Package('booktabs'))
>
> with doc.create(pl.Section('Matrix')):
>     doc.append(pl.Math(data=[pl.Matrix(M)]))
>
> # Difference to the other answer:
> with doc.create(pl.Section('Table')):
>     with doc.create(pl.Table(position='htbp')) as table:
>         table.add_caption('Test')
>         table.append(pl.Command('centering'))
>         table.append(pl.NoEscape(df.to_latex(escape=False)))
>
> doc.generate_pdf('full', clean_tex=False)
> ```

ちなみに`PyLaTeX`を入れるだけだと、回答の様には出来なくて、最後の行でLaTexコンパイラが必要というエラーが出てきます。

```
>>> doc.generate_pdf('full', clean_tex=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pylatex\document.py", line 280, in generate_pdf
    'Either specify a LaTex compiler ' +
pylatex.errors.CompilerError: No LaTex compiler was found
Either specify a LaTex compiler or make sure you have latexmk or pdfLaTex installed.
```

ただし以下のようにデータは出来ているようなので、上記エラーメッセージのようにLaTexコンパイラを入れれば目的は達成できるのではないでしょうか。

```
>>> doc
Document('default_filepath', [Command('normalsize', Arguments(), Options()), Section('Matrix', True, [Math([Matrix(matrix([[1, 9],
        [2, 8],
        [3, 7]], dtype=int64), [])])]), Section('Table', True, [Table([Command('caption', Arguments('Test'), Options()), Command('centering', Arguments(), Options()), NoEscape(\begin{tabular}{lrr}
\toprule
{} &  a &  b \\
x &    &    \\
\midrule
0 &  1 &  9 \\
1 &  2 &  8 \\
2 &  3 &  7 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
)])])])
```

関連：
[pandas.DataFrame.to_latex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html)
[PyLaTeX - PyPl](https://pypi.org/project/PyLaTeX/)
[Docs » PyLaTeX](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/index.html)

他にはこんなツールもあるようです。
[LaTeXの出力を多様な画像形式にするTeX2img](https://murabitoleg.com/latex-2/)
[TeX2img配布サイト](https://tex2img.tech/)